Как обернуть номер телефона в ссылку в письме телеграмм
Дублирую заявки с сайта в чат телеграмм
 $arr = array(
        'Форма заказать звонок со страницы' => $pageTitle,
        'Имя:' => $name,
        'Телефон:' => $phone,
        'Страница:' => THIS_URL
    );

        foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
            if ($key === 'Телефон:') {
                $value = "<a href='tel:$value'>$value</a>"; 
            }
            $txt .= "<b>".$key."</b> ".$value."%0A";
        };

Не понимаю как сделать так чтобы в письме номер телефона был обернут в ссылку. Подскажите, в чем проблема?

Так чат или письмо? Вообще телеграм сам подсвечивает номера, не нужно ничего делать

@AlexeyTen , вообще в чат. Везде написано что он сам должен понимать телефон как ссылку, но не понимаю по какой причине не оборачивается

Может у вас телефон в странном формате? Мне он подсвечивает почти любую достаточно длинную последовательность цифр.

По итогу нужно было удалить все лишние символы, кроме цифр и знака "+" через str_replace
